Issue Displaying Minor Tick Marks Using ggplot2
I am a beginner with R, but I am trying to make a plot with minor tick marks included on the x (by 5) and y (by 2.5) axes. I altered the theme_bw to alter the plot in ways I would like it; however, I am unsure if this may be suppressing my ability to see minor tick marks.
I have tried using the minor_breaks to add these tick marks; however, they have not showed up. Here is the code that I have with the first part being the alterations I made to the theme and the second part coding in the plot. I attached an image of the plot I am getting. You can see that there are no minor tick marks between the major tick marks that are labeled on both axes.
The plot that is output from my code. Note that there are no minor tick marks along either the x (by 5) or y (by 2.5) axes that I tried specifying with the minor_breaks function.
#Setting Up General Plot Theme:
  theme_set(theme_bw())
  theme_update(
    text = element_text(family = "Gill Sans MT", size = 14, color = "black"), # Set Font
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold"), # Bold X Axis Title
    axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", angle = 90), # Bold Y Axis Title
    axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12, color = "black", margin = margin(t = 5)), #Bold X Axis Text
    axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12, color = "black", margin = margin(r = 5)), # Bold Y Axis Text with margin at bottom
    axis.ticks = element_line(linewidth = 3, color = "black" ), # Increase Tick Mark Thickness
    axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25, "cm"), # Increase and Invert Tick Marks
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", linewidth = 3), # Increase Axis Thickness
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), # Remove Major Grid Lines
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank() # Remove Minor Grid Lines
  )
  
  # Plots:
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/KXghd.png)
  # Set X-Axis Bounds and Labels:
  x_bounds <- c(0, 90)  # Set the lower and upper bounds for the x-axis.
  x_labels <- seq(0, 100, by = 10)  # Define the labels for the x-axis.
  
  # Plotting:
  plot <- ggplot(melting_combined, aes(x = Temperature_M5, y = CD_M5)) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    labs(
      x = "Temperature (\u00b0C)",
      y = expression(bold(paste("MRE"[222], " \u00d7 10"^-3, " (deg cm"^2, "dmol"^-1, ")")))
    ) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand =  c(0, 0), minor_breaks = seq(-25, 0, by = 2.5), breaks = seq(-25, 0, by = 5), limits = c(-25, 0)) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), minor_breaks = seq(10, 90, by = 5), breaks = seq(10, 90, by = 10), limits = c(10, 90)) +
    coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
    theme(panel.border = element_rect(linewidth = 1, fill = NA),
          axis.ticks = element_line(linewidth = 1)
    )
    
  print(plot)


You can do this with the ggprism package.
library(ggprism)
library(ggplot2)

A <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
  geom_point()
  
B <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(guide = "prism_minor")


UPDATE:
Or using ggplot2 version 3.5.0 (published 2024-02-23):
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(guide=guide_axis(minor.ticks = TRUE))

(thanks to @teunbrand !)
Adding minor tick marks to the x axis in ggplot2 (with no labels)

You can also use guide = guide_axis(minor.ticks = TRUE) without resorting to extensions.
